# Rails generate migration not work after updating ruby version to 3.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

I have updated project ruby version from 2.3.1 to 3.0.2 with rails 6.1.4.1 and related changes.
All changes are working fine and also support rails db:migrate and related steps.

But when i try to generate new migration using "rails generate migration test_migration", Command will not response.

I dig more and found that in spring 3.0.0 , rub.rb when try to execute "server.gets.chomp", at that time system will not give any response.

```
def verify_server_version
        server_version = server.gets.chomp
```

Please provide any clue to solve this issue.

Is there anything i need to update? or change?

Answer (score 2):

Try `killall ruby` or `bin/spring stop`

Comment: Welcome to SO! It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Oh thanks so helpful. Ok, ill stick to the rules next time, just wanted to provide this `any clue` that hopefully works, obviously.